# Xls to CSV macro Conversion format for numbers

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro 'macro1' that convert all *.xls files within a folder to *.csv. After converting them, I merge rows using the command prompt. The I convert the merged file into an xls using macro2. Everything is working fine but when a value is something like 123456789123456 the resulting csv value is something like 1234E+11. How to keep the number format between converted files?

here are my macros

macro1

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertToCSV()

Dim i As Long
Dim NumFiles As Long
Dim FileName As String
Dim FileNames() As String


FileName = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "/*.xls")

NumFiles = 1
ReDim Preserve FileNames(1 To NumFiles)
FileNames(NumFiles) = FileName


Do While FileName <> ""
FileName = Dir()
If FileName <> "" Then
NumFiles = NumFiles + 1
ReDim Preserve FileNames(1 To NumFiles)
FileNames(NumFiles) = FileName
End If
Loop


Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For i = 1 To UBound(FileNames)
If FileNames(i) <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then

Workbooks.Open FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FileNames(i)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
FileName:=Left(FileNames(i), Len(FileNames(i)) - 4) & ".csv", _
FileFormat:=xlCSV
ActiveWorkbook.Close
End If
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

and the macro2

```
Sub FromCSVToXLS()
Dim myWB As Workbook, WB As Workbook
Dim L As Long, x As Long, i As Long

Dim v As Variant

Dim myPath

Dim myFile
Set myWB = ThisWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Sheets(1).Cells.ClearContents
myPath = "C:\Folder1\Folder2\"   '<<< change path
myFile = "myFile.csv"   '<<< change file name
Set WB = Workbooks.Open(myPath & myFile)
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Copy myWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
ActiveWorkbook.Close False
L = myWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 1 To L
v = Split(Cells(i, 1), ",")
For x = 0 To UBound(v)
Cells(i, x + 1) = v(x)
Next x
Next i
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= "D:\data folder\1.xls"

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
myWB.Save
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

PS: the command prompt is not altering the number format. VERIFIED!

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!!

I did this:

Open the merged file

select the concerned column

right clic on the column

and I changed the format of all column's cells.